# Ir para a próxima linha de uma tabela com while. É possível?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber se sem um cursor, eu tenho como de percorrer uma tabela dentro de um While. Exemplo, tenho esse bloco:

```
SET @CONT = 0
WHILE @cont < 3
BEGIN
 EXEC GP_ImprimeConsProdutosTipo ' and f.CodMaterial in (SELECT * FROM #PartNumberTemp)', 'SP', '', 0, 1, 0, 0,1,0, ''
 SET @cont = @cont + 1
END
```

A var @cont já foi declarada e etc. Essa query ela sempre trás o mesmo resultado 3 vezes, porque o parâmetro que é um select pega sempre o primeiro registro. A tabtemp tem 3 registros, logo a execução da proc deveria trazer 3 registros distintos e me trás 3 registros repetidos.

Há como fazer isso, simular um next sem um cursor em uma tabela?

***TabTemp: #PartNumberTemp***

Fiz dessa forma e rolou, mas fico com a sensação de Gambi. Quanto ao projeto inicial, alteramos e não precisei mais desse recurso, mas quis tentar para aprender. No momento desse post o banco estava indisponível e não pude testar o exemplo do ricidleiv, tão logo eu possa testo e posto. Eis como eu fiz

```
WHILE @cont < 5
BEGIN
 SET @novovalor = (select partnumber from #PartNumberTemp where idx = @cont)
 SET @whereproc = ' and f.CodMaterial = ''' + @novovalor + ''''
 EXEC GP_ImprimeConsProdutosTipo @whereproc, 'SP', '', 0, 1, 0, 0,1,0, ''
 SET @cont = @cont + 1
END
```

Criei na TabTemp um campo `IDX` tipo `int` e fiz o select de acordo com o valor de `IDX(Where)`

Comment: Se executar a proc fora do bloco while só me retorna um registro e não três e sempre o primeiro

Comment: Eu não entendi onde a variavel @cont influencia no select

Comment: Ou é para fazer o mesmo select 3 vezes?

Comment: não influencia, em realidade a fiz na mão para testes.há 3 registros na tabela e a proc deve ser executada 3 vezes passando um partnumber. como são 3, deveria retornar 3 registros da proc. a @cont é só para testes de um while. Recebo 3 registros, mas iguais

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, assim. Na proc há um select que recebe esse parâmetro na where dele: `' and f.codmaterial...'`. Sendo que CodMaterial e Partnumber são a mesma coisa. Então para cada Partnumber passado, a proc me retorna um registro com descrição, preço, imposto e etc.. Se passo 3 partnumber, receberei 3 registros diferentes. Na forma que fiz isso não rola, pois no while só pega o primeiro registro(não tem next) no select da tabtemp, entende

Comment: Sim. Acho que sim. Tem de ser escrito de outra forma, porque do jeito que está o parâmetro não muda. Tem de amarrar o @cont ao parâmetro ou select top(@cont) order by alguma coisa e devolve o ultimo ou todos. Sei lá. rsrs

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo, entendi. Acho que dessa forma sem cursor, não rola. Tudo que fizer vai parecer gambi. De qualquer forma agradeço.

Comment: Passar um `WHERE` dentro de um parâmetro para concatenar com uma `SQL` é uma **péssima** prática. Aconselho rever o problema para achar uma solução mais adequada para este problema

Answer (score 1):

Sem utilizar cursor, você pode utilizar a estratégia de ROW_NUMBER() e filtrar a cada iteração a linha de acordo com o valor de @count.

Desta forma, você necessitaria alterar o SELECT por trás da Stored Procedure `GP_ImprimeConsProdutosTipo`, adicionando uma nova coluna e filtrando pelo parâmetro do contador, exemplo:

```
WITH CTE_CONSULTA
AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ...
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [id]) AS NumeroDaLinha
    FROM ...
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_CONSULTA
WHERE NumeroDaLinha = @contador
```

Comment: Penso que na maioria dos cenários, o uso do CURSOR é o mais performático e recomendável.